# How can I pull Vue Router pages from the server?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vue-router

I'm building an Electron app that needs to have multiple pages. I've looked at Vue Router (I'm already using Vue) as a routing system, but I'd like to store every page a a separate HTML file.

I've tried a couple of things:

- Making an Ajax request to the page, then putting its contents into the route. When trying to navigate to the route, I got a `route not allowed` error.
- Making an Ajax request to the page, then replacing the `#app` element's contents with the requested page. This caused the `{{ template_things }}` to stop working.

I'm open to using other routing systems, too. Vue Router just seemed the most convenient.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you want to bypass the main advantage of Vue. Why? And if so, why don't you just use VanillaJS with HTML instead?

Comment: The Approach you are trying is micro-frontends, this could help
https://dev.to/phodal/micro-frontend-architecture-in-action-4n60#route-dispatch-micro-frontends

Answer (score 1):

You could try out [Nuxt.JS](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/).

The big innovation of Nuxt.js comes with the `nuxt generate` command.
When building your application, it will generate the HTML for every one of your routes and store it in a file.

For example, the following file structure:

```
-| pages/
----| about.vue
----| index.vue
```

Will generate:

```
-| dist/
----| about/
------| index.html
----| index.html
```

There is an Electron starter app with Nuxt on [GitHub](https://github.com/nuxt-community/electron-template)